# Is there any way to let click Binding allow validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion and Knockoutjs app. I want to apply jQuery validation but the click binding doesn't allow me. Validation is fine when `data-bind=" click: "` is removed. Here is a basic validation:

```
$("#datepick").ejDatePicker({
  validationRules: {
    required: true
  },
  validationMessage: {
    required: "Required Date value"
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: create">Submit</button>
```

No error messages. When I click the submit button it applies the binding and ignores the validation.

Comment: There are specific KO plugins, see here: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Plugins

Comment: Thanks, but it works without the plugins, I missed the validation condition: (.valid()), and when I clean my code I correct that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further analysis of your provided code block, you may miss to validate the date picker element on button click action or else improperly specify the jquery validation script in your application. Could you please check the below playground?

https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/0mdc3j0g

Note: If customize any submit action, we need to validate the corresponding inputs in click action.